# Recursive CTE in SQLAlchemy (Mysql database) not working

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I am getting error while using recursive cte query over mysql database

*ERRORS(pymysql.err.ProgrammingError) (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'RECURSIVE cte*

```
    top_level = db.session.query(Group)
    top_level = top_level.filter(Group.id == group_id)
    top_level = top_level.cte('cte', recursive=True)
    bottom_level = db.session.query(Group)
    bottom_level = bottom_level.join(top_level, Group.parent_id == top_level.c.id)
    hierarchy_query = top_level.union(bottom_level)
    client_rows = db.session.query(hierarchy_query).all()
```

Could you please let me know what the issue is.

Comment: Looks like your DBMS version is too old and does not support CTEs.

Comment: So what is the workaround.

Comment: The solution is MySQL upgrade. The workaround is using iterative stored procedure instead of single query with recursive CTE.

Comment: Can you please provide me with the stored procedure solution.

Comment: No. I don't understand sqlalchemy codes.

Comment: I have mysql version 8.0.25 which supports CTE

Comment: If so then: enable General Log temporarily; execute your code; retrieve complete SQL code received by MySQL from the log; provide this SQL code. Also test this code using CLI - does it produces the same error message precisely?

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your issue with the latest version of SQLAlchemy against MySQL 8.0.21. Adding `echo=True` to my `create_engine()` call and running your code shows that SQLAlchemy renders [this](https://pastebin.com/iVwFde0C) which does not cause MySQL to throw an error.